# C# - Writing to a multiline textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm trying to write the status of the program to the user. But my method to do so doesn't work. statusBox is a textbox windows form.

```
   public static void writetoStatus(string text)
        {
            TextBox statusBox = new TextBox(); 
            statusBox.Text = text;
        }
```

Help please!

Comment: looks alright there must be some other problem like no tect in text variable or wrong textbox name?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your method, but the fact it's static makes me want to see the code around it.  Other questions to answer: Does this compile?  Is this ASP.NET or a windows form?

Comment: actually I didnt understand what do you want to do? Are trying to create multiline textBox (as I understand from title) or trying to update any textBox's text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access instance variables with a static method.  I can't think of a way that `statusBox` would not be an instance member.  Try making your method non-static and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks so much! I removed the line creating a new textbox. Got rid of the static in my method and now it works. Simpler than I thought! :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a previous answer, your method needs to be static in order to access the `TextBox` on your form.

Also pressing, however is the fact that you're putting the status in a new `TextBox` instead of the one on your form.

If you created a form and put a `TextBox` on it, then the `TextBox` already has a name, and you can access it from the code-behind file. By default, I think it would be `Textbox1` or some other number. You can, of course, change this name in the designer file or in the form editor GUI in Visual Studio.

So, lets say you change the name of the existing `TextBox` to `statusBox`. Now your method need only be this:

```
void WriteToStatus(string status)
{
    statusBox.Text = status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i see that you are creating a new instance of text box inside static method. That instance of textbox ends up nowhere and it's destroyed once you your static method is executed.

You can either have:

```
    public static void writetoStatus(TextBox tb, string text)
    {
        tb.Text = text;
    }

    // and then later use it like: 
    writetoStatus(statusBox, text);
```

Or:

```
    public static void writetoStatus(Form frm, string text)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Text = text;
        frm.Controls.Add(tb);
    }

    // and then later use it like: 
    writetoStatus(myForm, text);
```